# Laravel, Vuejs, axios get posts for logged in user

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, post, axios

I am trying to get the tasks of the logged in user into a vuejs component via axios but I keep getting

> POST http://localhost:8000/api/tasks 401 (Unauthorized)

Here's the routes from api.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

    Route::prefix('tasks')->group(function() {
        Route::post('/', 'TasksController@index');
        Route::post('{id}', 'TasksController@single');
        Route::post('new', 'TasksController@new');
    });

});
```

The `index` function of `TasksController`:

```
public function index(Request $request) {

    if ( $request->ajax() ) {
        return auth()->user()->tasks()->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();
    }

    return view('tasks.index')
                ->with('tasks', auth()->user()->tasks()->orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get());

}
```

And the vuejs component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="task in tasks" v-bind:key="task.id">{{ task.name }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                tasks: [],
            }
        },

        created() {
            this.fetchTasks();
        },

        methods: {

            fetchTasks() {
                axios({
                    url: 'api/tasks',
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                }).then(res => {
                    this.tasks = res.data;
                });
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: 401 error occurs when you are not authenticated/logged in.

Comment: I know, the problem is I WAS already logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `auth:api` middleware, this is by default a token based authentication but I don't see you adding any `Bearer` token header.

There are 2 possible solutions that I know.

1. If you want to keep using the `auth:api` middleware, request an api token and use that in your requests (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication), but it would be better to switch to [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport)
2. Personally I would use web auth for this (session based), after you login a session token will be added and you don't really have to do much with it because it will be added to all calls after that